# Official London shapefiles not working

Tags: shapefile, r, leaflet

I am trying to map the Lower-layer Super Output Area (LSOA)of London. I could only find the shapefiles in this address:

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/6cdebf5d-c69b-4480-8c9c-53ab8a816b9d/statistical-gis-boundary-files-for-london

in the following zip file:

"statistical-gis-boundaries-london.zip"

Below is the code I'm using to map the shapfiles using R.

```
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

lsao <- readOGR(dsn = "ESRI", layer = "LSOA_2011_London_gen_MHW") #Read the shapefiles from the ESRI folder

lsao %>% 
leaflet() %>%
  setView(-0.1000, 51.5,zoom = 10) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons()
```

The above code just opens a Leaflet map with no polygons on the map. I have never had a problem mapping shapefiles using the above code and that's why I think there might be something wrong with the shapefiles on the UK government website. I was wondering if anyone has more information on this issue?

Comment: I can't see any shapefiles on that page - only CSV and XLS and ZIPs of those.

Comment: @Spacedman just updated the post.

Comment: You don't say what you expect to happen from your code and what actually happens.

Comment: @bugmenot123 sorry, just updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below code:

```
lsao_london <- readOGR(dsn="folder name", layer="data name")
lsao_london <- spTransform(, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The data needs to be transformed to lat-long coordinates (EPSG:4326) to work with leaflet. For `sp` classes, use `spTransform`, but it is recommended you use `sf` package functions for spatial data, so read in with `st_read` and use `st_transform` to reproject.

Comment: Thank you, I am fairly new to these stuff, would you please share the correct code for reading the file and transforming it? I have no idea how to use st_read & st_transform.

Comment: You're probably better off finding a tutorial for spatial data in R than for me to feed you code here. https://bookdown.org/robinlovelace/geocompr/ and go through a few chapters.